# Setting the date in an elsarticle

Tags: datetime, elsarticle

Consider the following `elsarticle` document:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\journal{Journal of something}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{My article}
\begin{abstract}
Summary
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it shows the date in the bottom right corner. How can I change this? The obvious `\date` does not seem to work (but gives no error).

Answer (score 6):

`elsarticle` shows the current date in the bottom right corner, so you can avoid this by

```
\let\today\relax
```

or change it by redefining `\today` to show a certain date, such as

```
\renewcommand*{\today}{1.1.2011}
```

Other possibilities include redefining interal macros such as `\@oddfoot` or `\ps@pprintTitle` or redefining the page style, which is `pprintTitle`.

Comment: Redefining `\today` works, although I don't find it very elegant. Thanks!